My question was closed, due to being unanswerable. But I solved it, where do I put the answer?
I asked a question which was closed due to needs to be more focused. I asked another similar, which was then closed due to needs details or clarity.
It appears to primary reason for closure wasn't due to lack of clarity, but instead due to the perception of it being unsolvable.
I've solved it, exactly within the requirements stated, in a fairly general way which I think may benefit others. But... because the question is closed, I can't exactly post the answer there.
Where should I post the answer?
I'm not sure if this is discussion or support, so I added both tags. If there IS site functionality that solves this, I think it's support. Otherwise, I think I guess it's discussion.

It's open now, please add your answer. That's not to say this meta question isn't still valid btw

Questions shouldn’t be closed for being “unanswerable”. My favourite kinds of questions are those that don’t have a “proper” answer, but for which some kind of clever hack is possible. So, I’m not sure this question has a useful answer because it describes a situation that shouldn’t exist, and the problem should be addressed at that level.

@JeremyBanks it's also all too probable for an impossible answer to be possible given time

One thing I hear you doing which you shouldn’t be doing is asking a question and the if it’s closed asking the same question just slightly different instead of going through the process to reopen the original question

@SecurityHound yow. Punctuation dude. It's way too Friday for a comment like that.

@Gimby - Here are a few free punctuation marks, (“.”, “,”, “?”, “!”), have at it!!

I see no evidence that it was closed "due to the perception of it being unsolvable". It may be perceived as such, but it's not fair to assume that's why it was closed.
